# Approach to create aside menu with html5

Tags: css, html

Firstly, look this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Uuyp8/5/

I need to create block like block in next image in the `<aside>` block.

[image: block]

Don't pay attention to russian words. It's not the question.

I can create such block with next html structure:

```
<aside>
    <div class='block'>
        <div class='header'><h1>Lorem block 2</h1></div>
        <div class='content'>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer ullamcorper posuere pretium. Mauris vitae pharetra nisl.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='block'>
        <div class='header'><h1>Lorem block 1</h1></div>
        <div class='content'>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer ullamcorper posuere pretium. Mauris vitae pharetra nisl.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</aside>
```

Questions:

1) is it ok to use new html5 tags like `<aside>` or `<section>` with `<div>` blocks like in my example?

2) how I can create such block only with html5 tags?

3) Do I need to use only html5 tags or it is normal practic to use both html5 tags and old divs?

Answer (score 1):

Divs aren't "old". They still have theire place like `<span>` and many others.

See [here](http://html5doctor.com/you-can-still-use-div/)

QUOTE :

> “Sorry, can you say that again?”, I hear you ask. Certainly: you can still use `<div>`! Despite HTML5 bringing us new elements like `<article>`, `<section>`, and `<aside>`, the `<div>` element still has its place. Let the HTML5 Doctor tell you why.

So you don't have to ban them from your web pages and you should still use them like you are.

Comment: so its is ok what I did to create menu and no need another way, right?

Comment: @SharikovVladislav Your menu is inside a `<nav>` tag witch why it was created (to make links between your web pages) so it is ok.